# Существует ли подобный софт для windows?

Tags: windows, безопасность, поиск-программ, пароль

Всем знатокам привет. Подскажите пожалуйста ищу нечто похожее на это:

1. При входе в систему windows запрашивает пароль.
2. Вводим (например) 1234 и получаем успешную авторизацию, с последующим открытием сессии, рабочего стола и т.д.
3. Вводим пароль 4321, так же успешная авторизация но при этом, сразу запускается cmd.
4. Вводим пароль 6969, по прежнему успешная авторизация но при этом выполнение команды, например очистить указанную папку.

Если в кратце, то ищу менеджер паролей, что бы для каждого пароля можно было настроить определенные действия.

Comment: а еще если такое есть, было бы неплохо скрыть сообщение о провальной попытке авторизации.
незачем всяким знать о том, что они ввели неверный пароль.

Comment: Если «всякие» увидят, что любой пароль является верным, это станет ещё более подозрительно

Comment: А они не увидят, вы не беспокойтесь об этом.

Comment: тут и сторонний софт кмк не особо то и нужен. в самой винде создаете столько пользователей, сколько нужно вариантов запуска и бросаете всё уникальное в личную папку автозапуска нужного пользователя. после включаете авторизацию при запуске и все дела. только перед использованием всего этого на реальном железе, потренируйтесь в виртуалке

Comment: ну как костыль может сойти, но плодить туеву хучу пользователей, да и планировщик задействовать не особо хотелось бы